# Algorithm for finding many gcd(a,b) over a range of a?

Tags: number-theory

I have a procedure where I calculate gcd(a,b) many times, and it can be computationally expensive. I am trying to instead create an array containing gcd(a,b) values by using a factor sieve of some kind, but I don't know a good way to do it.

For instance if I am looking at $a=24$ then I'd be looking for a way to calculate many gcd(24,b) values in one loop or something similar.

I hope I am making sense!

Comment: Why is computing a gcd computationally expensive? How large are your numbers?

Comment: @lhf 20k loop by 20k loop or so (these also represent the size of the numbers)

Comment: Is this quicker to just do it the way I am doing it?

Comment: For a fixed $a$, $\gcd(a,b)$ is periodic of period $a$.

Comment: @lhf Do you mean gcd(a,b)=gcd(a,kb)?

Comment: I want to create a matrix of gcd(a,b) as fast as possible

Comment: I mean $gcd(a,b)=gcd(a,b+ka)$.

Comment: @lhf there's no way to do it using some sort of factor sieve technique?

Comment: I think the Euclidean algorithm is fast enough

Comment: Haven't you tried the Euclidean Algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mathematica will vectorize this automatically for you, which be much faster than an explicit loop.

E.g. finding $gcd(a,b)$ where $a$ is a 70 digit number and $b$ ranges over a list of 10K composite numbers of the same magnitude took about 0.1 seconds. *Just now, on a fairly old machine.*

The Mathematica code is simply

> mygcds = GCD[a,B];

where $B$ is the list containing the numbers $b$.

Comment: I'm not using Mathematica; I'm writing my own code for this, but thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

In APL (NARS2000, free) :

```
      size ← 15

      2 2⍴(0)((1,size)⍴⍳size)((size,1)⍴⍳size)(gcd_sieve size)
  0   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 

  1   1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  1  1  1  1  1  1 
  2   1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1  2  1  2  1  2  1 
  3   1 1 3 1 1 3 1 1 3  1  1  3  1  1  3 
  4   1 2 1 4 1 2 1 4 1  2  1  4  1  2  1 
  5   1 1 1 1 5 1 1 1 1  5  1  1  1  1  5 
  6   1 2 3 2 1 6 1 2 3  2  1  6  1  2  3 
  7   1 1 1 1 1 1 7 1 1  1  1  1  1  7  1 
  8   1 2 1 4 1 2 1 8 1  2  1  4  1  2  1 
  9   1 1 3 1 1 3 1 1 9  1  1  3  1  1  3 
 10   1 2 1 2 5 2 1 2 1 10  1  2  1  2  5 
 11   1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  1 11  1  1  1  1 
 12   1 2 3 4 1 6 1 4 3  2  1 12  1  2  3 
 13   1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  1  1  1 13  1  1 
 14   1 2 1 2 1 2 7 2 1  2  1  2  1 14  1 
 15   1 1 3 1 5 3 1 1 3  5  1  3  1  1 15
```

And copy + paste this code :

```
      ⎕cr'gcd_sieve'
gcdmatrix ← gcd_sieve size;i;temp                              
gcdmatrix ← (size,size)⍴1                                      
:for i :in 1+⍳¯1+⌊size÷2                                       
  gcdmatrix[i×temp∘.,temp←⍳⌊size÷i] ← i                        
:endfor                                                        
gcdmatrix[⊂[2]((⌈size÷2),2)⍴2/temp] ← temp ← (⌊size÷2)+⍳⌈size÷2
```

Example

```
      gcd_array ← gcd_sieve 15

      gcd_array[8;12]
4
      gcd_array[12;6]
6
      gcd_array[7;5]
1
```

Have a nice day.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  Thank you for the solution; however this problem was asked 5 months ago and your hard work might not be as appreciated as had you solved a more recent problem.